# Getting the multiplicative inverse of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have a polynomial $m(x)=  x^2 + x + 2$ that's irreducible over $F=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. I need to calculate the multiplicative inverse of the polynomial $2x+1$ in $F/(m(x))$.

I'd normally use division with two polynomials like this, but it doesn't work here. So how can I get the inverse?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite field, so just use Euclid's algorithm to find polynomials $a(x), b(x)$ with $a(x)m(x) + b(x)(2x+1) \equiv 1\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Working in $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[[x]]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$, 
one (awful) way to do it is to notice that $2x + 1 = 1 - x$, so
$$(2x+1)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dotsb. $$
But $1 + x + x^2 = -1 = 2$ 
and, since $x^2 = -x - 2 = 1-x$,
$$x^3 + \dotsb = \frac{x^3}{1-x} = \frac{x^3}{x^2} = x,$$
giving $(2x+1)^{-1} = 2 + x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can just let the unknown inverse be $ax+b$ and then multiply $(ax+b)(2x+1)=2ax^2+(a+2b)x+b.$ Equate this to $1$ in $Z_3[x]/(m)$ which means using $x^2=-x-2$ that the term $2ax^2$ becomes $2a(-x-2)=-2ax-4,$ which is then added to $(a+2b)x+b.$ Try from there.

I'm pretty sure this method should work, though in a comment, the user Unit already gave the result.

Comment: The inverse is actually $x+2$.